# Почему не работает код? Строки/python

Tags: python, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает? Я написал этот код сам, а затем сверил с учителем - все одинаково - но у него работает исправно, а у меня нет. В итоге программа должна вывести "4477". *Заранее спасибо*

```
s = '7' * 96 + '4' * 24
while '4444' in s or '7777' in s:
    if '4444' in s:
        s = s.replace('4444', '77', 1)
    else:
        s = s.replace('4444', '44', 1)
print(s)
```

Comment: не может быть, что все одинаково. А не работает, потому что одно из условий в ``while '4444' in s or '7777' in s`` всегда выполняется.

Comment: если 1 в 1, значит и у него не работает. инфа 100%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while '4444' in s or '7777' in s:
```

означает, что цикл будет работать, если в цикле у вас встречается или `4444` или `7777` или и то и другое

в самом цикле вы выполняете замену ТОЛЬКО `4444`

```
if '4444' in s:
    s = s.replace('4444', '77', 1)
else:
    s = s.replace('4444', '44', 1)
```

а строку формируете, содержащую и `7777`:

```
s = '7' * 96 + '4' * 24
```

таким образом, чтобы ни происходило в цикле, ваша строка будет всегда содержать `7777`, а значит цикл будет протекать вечно

Вот такой код работал бы конечное время:

```
s = '7' * 96 + '4' * 24

while '4444' in s or '7777' in s:
    if '4444' in s:
        s = s.replace('4444', '77', 1)
    else:
        s = s.replace('7777', '44', 1)

print(s)
```

в нем происходит и замена 4ок и замена 7ок и происходит выход из цикла (получается `4477`)